# How to build a dataframe from a scraped table

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance

I'm trying my luck at webscraping again. This time I'm using python-3.6 to try and transform the table at https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/KEPL3.SA into a dataframe in order to build a [Piotroski F- score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piotroski_F-Score) for companies listed on Brazil's Stock Exchange, BOVESPA. Although I've looked up on the internet and found Quantopian and Quandl solutions (ready and free-ish), they do not seem to work with Brazilian assets, thus my intention to at least start building on something like that. I'm starting with python and beautiful soup, so nevermind my dumb code.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/KEPL3.SA")
res.raise_for_status()

rawsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

for row in rawsoup.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    print(cols)
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
$ python3 reuters_data.py 
[]
[]
[<td>P/E Ratio (TTM)</td>, <td class="data">--</td>, <td class="data">15.32</td>, <td class="data">24.24</td>]
[<td>
           P/E High - Last 5 Yrs.</td>, <td class="data">67.86</td>, <td class="data">36.54</td>, <td class="data">39.87</td>]
[<td>              
          P/E Low - Last 5 Yrs.</td>, <td class="data">9.48</td>, <td class="data">8.71</td>, <td class="data">15.24</td>]
[<td colspan="5"></td>]
[<td>
          Beta</td>, <td class="data">0.64</td>, <td class="data">1.33</td>, <td class="data">1.01</td>]
[<td colspan="5"></td>]
[<td>
          Price to Sales (TTM)</td>, <td class="data">0.43</td>, <td class="data">1.29</td>, <td class="data">2.27</td>]
[<td>
          Price to Book (MRQ)</td>, <td class="data">0.58</td>, <td class="data">2.13</td>, <td class="data">2.70</td>]
[<td>
          Price to Tangible Book (MRQ)</td>, <td class="data">0.65</td>, <td class="data">2.74</td>, <td class="data">5.41</td>]
[<td>
          Price to Cash Flow (TTM)</td>, <td class="data">--</td>, <td class="data">9.83</td>, <td class="data">15.03</td>]
.
.
.
[<td><strong># Net Buyers:</strong></td>, <td class="data"> <span class="changeUp">1</span> </td>]
```

(I've ommited a part of the results in the middle, but it's all there)

Now I've reached a wall and I don't know how to properly transform this into a dataframe so I can actually do math with those numbers on the table.

Any help is appreciated, and if my source is bad or there is a better one, please feel free to point me out as well.

Thank you very very much. Looking forward to the answers.

Comment: Does the built-in `[read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html)` function help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your script like this and work from that:

```
import requests, bs4
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/KEPL3.SA")
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, features="lxml")
# find all 'table' tags in the html document
data_table = soup.findAll('table', {"class": "dataTable"})
i = 0
# Create an empty dictionary to be used later with pandas
Dict = {}
current_header = ""
# only second table matters that's why the index starts with 1
# then find every tr tag with the class= stripe according to the url you gave
for row in data_table[1].findAll('tr', {"class": "stripe"}):
    # find every td tag inside the 'tr' tags
    for cells in row.findAll('td'):
        # on your case every 4th row is a header so we use this as a dictionary key
        if i % 4 == 0:
            current_header = str(cells.find(text=True)).strip()
            # add some sanitization at the header title and add to the Dictionary
            Dict[str(cells.find(text=True)).strip()] = []
        else:
            data = cells.find(text=True)
            # try to parse the data as a float, othewise is a '--' 
            # and we should use the 0 to better represent the value as a number
            try:
                data = float(data)
            except:
                data = 0
            # append the values into the dictionary key(header)                
            Dict[current_header].append(data)
        i += 1

# Now you have a data similar to Dict= {'P/E Ratio (TTM)': [0, 15.32, 24.24], ...}
# using pandas we create a data frame from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
print(df.head)
```